# How to add a background image in html from local folder

Tags: html, image

I need some help in understanding how I can get the following HTML coding to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<title>YAHUAS</title>

<style>
body {
  background-image: url("Pictures/Yahuas.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<a href="student.php">Student data</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Should I be changing the following - background-image: `url("Pictures/Yahuas.png");` so that it goes to the folder in the `C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Bradford College\Advance Database\YAHUAS\PHP and HTML` where this image is stored?

Comment: Try with `./Pictures/Yahuas.png`.

Comment: Browser security should not allow to access local files.
You have to put it where your webserver can reach it with a absolut or relative path respectiv to the domain.

Answer (score 0):

If the Pictures folder is located in the same path as your html file is, then it should work. Could you double check that the Pictures folder and your saved html file are in the same path?

I don't think you want to use the absolute path to the image unless you are going to view the html file only on your own computer. If you would put it on a web server or any other computer it is highly unlikely that the image would be found in the same path.

Comment: Hi Mattias, I have tried all the variations and it still does not work. the image is stored in my shared drive path C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Bradford College\Advance Database\YAHUAS\PHP and HTML\Images

Comment: Is the full path to the image
C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Bradford College\Advance Database\YAHUAS\PHP and HTML\Images\Yahuas.png or is it
C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Bradford College\Advance Database\YAHUAS\PHP and HTML\Images\Pictures\Yahuas.png ?

I mean that c:\test\file.html and c:\test\Pictures\Yahuas.png (exchange test for the rest of your long path) should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is not really clear. However, I will assume you are trying to pick your image from the back of your folders/directories or from another Drive (e.g. C, D, F).

The Answer is **Yes**, You can Either use a backslash (Windows) or a forward-slash (Linux) with a full path or you can use a relative path if the image is present in the current directory or back directory.

```
<style>
   body {
      // Another Drive
      background-image: url("C:/Users/user/My OneDrive/Pictures/pic.png");

      // Relative Path
      background-image: url("Pictures/pic.png");
      // OR 
      background-image: url("./Pictures/pic.png");

      // Back Directory/Folder
      background-image: url("../Pictures/pic.png");
   }
</style>
```

Comment: Hi Mattias, I have tried all the variations and it still does not work. the image is stored in my shared drive path C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Bradford College\Advance Database\YAHUAS\PHP and HTML\Images

Comment: This should work
`url("C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Bradford College\Advance Database\YAHUAS\PHP and HTML\Images\Yahuas.png")` and if it is inside Pictures of that path then add \Pictures before the image name as well

Answer (score 0):

You should give to the exact URL Path

```
    <style>
    
      body {
        background-image: url("./Pictures/Yahuas.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
      }
    
    </style>
```

Comment: Hiya, I have tried all the variations and it still does not work. the image is stored in my shared drive path C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Bradford College\Advance Database\YAHUAS\PHP and HTML\Images